# Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>` DRF

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am receiving the error

> Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be
> returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`
> In Django DRF,

in my query i am trying to get the count of all related items to one specific item

the views.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def getVesselInfo(request):
    vessels = (Vessel.objects.annotate(
        Count('vessel_components', distinct=True)))
    vSerializer = VesselSerializer(vessels, many=True)
    return Response(vSerializer.data,)
```

models.py:

```
class Vessel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    imo = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Component(MP_Node):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    remarks = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    vessel = models.ForeignKey(
        Vessel, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='vessel_components')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Are you sure `Response` is an instance of  `rest_framework.response.Response`?

Comment: Could you also add your full error trace back to this question?

Comment: I tried to implement the above scenario but I am not getting any error.

Comment: @lucutzu33 I have (from rest_framework.response import Response) so i am guessing yes

Comment: @DeepakTripathi line by line ? could it be just an ident error that i am missing then ?

Comment: Yes it could be indent error because I have run the same code and its running fine on my side with custom model

Comment: @DeepakTripathi why thank you, it was an ident error.